# How to get OpenIdConnectOptions StateDataFormat

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid

I have a custom Open Id Connect server using [IdentityServer4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4). This SSO server has a custom endpoint for a non-standard Open Id Connect operation.

In order to use this operation I need to create a state parameter in the client application's request. The client application is a dotnet core 3.0 preview application with blazor server side.

I am registering the SSO provider with the following:

```
       services.AddAuthentication(options => {
         options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
       })
         .AddCookie()
         .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => {
           options.ClientId = oidcClientId;
           options.ClientSecret = "secret";
           options.Authority = "https://test.org";
           options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
           options.Scope.Clear();
           options.Scope.Add("openid");
           options.Scope.Add("extra");
           options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
           options.SaveTokens = true;
           options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
       });
```

The basic login/logout flow works as expected and does not have any issues.

The custom link I generate to use the custom SSO function looks like the following (razor):

```
            <a href=@($"https://test.org/custom/change-organization/{organization.OrganizationCode}?client_id=local-data-manager&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc&response_type=code id_token&scope=openid custom profile&nonce={GenerateNonce()}&state={GenerateState()}")>@organization.Name</a>
```

With the defined methods:

```
  private string GenerateNonce()
  {
    string nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
    return DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "." + nonce;
  }

  private string GenerateState()
  {
    var state = GenerateNonce();
    AuthenticationProperties authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
    (
      new Dictionary<string, string>
      {
        { OpenIdConnectDefaults.UserstatePropertiesKey, state },
      }
    );

    authProperties.RedirectUri = "http://localhost:5000";

    //This StateDataFormat does not use the correct DataProtectionProvider
    return openIdOptions.CurrentValue.StateDataFormat.Protect(authProperties);
  }
```

Where `openIdOptions` is dependency injected. As `@inject IOptionsMonitor<OpenIdConnectOptions> openIdOptions`

When I click the  tag and trigger the custom flow everything works as expected on the SSO side, but when the message comes back I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.                                                                                                                                             
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.                                           
System.Exception: Unable to unprotect the message.State.
```

This is thrown [from the OpenIdHandler](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/v3.0.0-preview8.19405.7/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs) which calls `Unprotect` on what I would assume to be the same `StateDataFormat` protector as was injected earlier:

`Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(message.State);`

From verbose logging I see the following when calling `GenerateState()`:

```
trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector[31]
Performing protect operation to key {cdf7e79b-8d1a-4e7e-a093-fea402dbba8c} with purposes ('/app/DataManager', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler', '', 'v1').
```

But when the request comes back I get the unprotect log:

```
trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector[5]
Performing unprotect operation to key {cdf7e79b-8d1a-4e7e-a093-fea402dbba8c} with purposes ('/app/DataManager', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler', 'oidc', 'v1').
```

The key difference is that the DataProtector "purposes" are different ( one having '' and one having 'oidc'). [Which according to the documentation means they are being encrypted and decrypted differently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.dataprotector?view=netframework-4.8).

I would expect the data protectors to be the same as they both refer to the same `OpenIdConnectOptions` that are configured.

Why is that the two `DataProtector`'s are providing different purposes? Are they different objects? Am I missing something in my configuration? How do I get the same provider from the internal framework and what I inject?

Comment: I am facing a very similar problem. Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: You use the data protection API both in AddOpenID Connect (to encrypt the state) and in AddCookie handler to encrypt the Auth Cookie. I recently blogged about the state and nonce parameter here:
* Demystifying OpenID Connect’s State and Nonce Parameters in ASP.NET Core - https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: I also blogged about how to peek inside the auth cookie here - Exploring what is inside the ASP.NET Core cookies - https://nestenius.se/2023/11/22/exploring-what-is-inside-the-asp-net-core-cookies/

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and found the answer, we need to get by scheme name to get the correct instance:

```
return _openIdOptions.Get("oidc").CurrentValue.StateDataFormat.Protect(authProperties);
```

Comment: Major champ answer, was going crazy looking for how to get the openIdConnectOptions in a unit test ;DD

Answer (score 0):

I found that in addition to Generating the state string, I also had to add a Correlation Cookie. See the `GenerateCorrelationId` method on the `RemoteAuthenticationHandel.cs` here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/RemoteAuthenticationHandler.cs#L220

I also found I had to add the correct key/value pairs on the `AuthenticationProperties` object (.xsrf, .redirect, etc)

My code looks something like this
Methods

```
    private string GenerateState(OpenIdConnectOptions openIdOptions, string nonce)
    {
        AuthenticationProperties authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties();
        authProperties.Items.Add(".xsrf", nonce);
        authProperties.Items.Add(".redirect", "/");
        authProperties.Items.Add("OpenIdConnect.Code.RedirectUri", $"https://{this.Request.Host}/signin-auth0";

        //This StateDataFormat does not use the correct DataProtectionProvider
        return openIdOptions.StateDataFormat.Protect(authProperties);
    }

    private string GenerateNonce()
    {
        string nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
        return DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "." + nonce;
    }
```

Main Controller Action

```
        OpenIdConnectOptions opts = _openIdOptions.Get("Auth0");
        string correlationId = GenerateNonce();
        string state = GenerateState(opts, correlationId);

        string cookieName = opts.CorrelationCookie.Name + correlationId;

        CookieOptions cookieOptions = opts.CorrelationCookie.Build(this.HttpContext, DateTime.UtcNow);

        Response.Cookies.Append(cookieName, "N", cookieOptions);

        ViewBag.State = state;
        return View();
```

Passing the state variable to the external provider will be returned to the OpenIdConnector middleware and should validate correctly.