# Openid - Is there a way to get the state & nonce generated by Challenge method without redirection?

Tags: oauth, identityserver4, openid-connect, microsoft-identity-platform

I have a requirement to integrate with an external authentication provider which they require us to generate the state & nonce and using these parameters as an input for the embedded JS to generate the QR code, this QR code will be scanned by mobile for authentication.

for the standard login with external authentication provider, we call the Challenge() method to redirect to the login page, and the redirect url contains the state & nonce itself, is there a way to generate/get them without redirection?

If I generate random nonce & state at frontend side then scanning the QR code and completed the authentication in mobile, it returned the authentication code and threw "unable to unprotect the message.State." exception at the IS4, I tried to disable the state validation but it does not work.

```
configureOptions.ProtocolValidator = new OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator()
{
    RequireState = false,
    RequireStateValidation = false,
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have found an answer for this one at the link below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57581119/how-to-get-openidconnectoptions-statedataformat/66485547#66485547